# Rewrite rule to redirect to file and not folder with same name

Tags: .htaccess

I am working on a new website and I want the following url `/newsite/products` to redirect to `/newsite/products/product.php`.

My .htaccess file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^newsite/products$ /newsite/products/product.php
```

My problem is that there is already a folder called `products` within `newsite` and when requesting `newsite/products` it tries to open that folder rather than go to the php file.

I get:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /newsite/products/ on this server.
```

Is there any way to make this work?

EDIT: Requested url is: http://example.com/newsite/products and location of `.htaccess` is in root.

Comment: Since you rewrite to `/newsite/products/product.php` it obviously _has to_ enter that folder. Most likely it does not have permission for that, either by your configuration elsewhere or because of file system permissions.

Comment: @arkascha I can open the file by manually entering http://..../newsite/products/product.php and the folder permissions are 755. I believe I get the error because requesting `newsite/products` defaults to viewing folder contents (hence the 403) and never does the redirect.

Comment: No, that is not correct, there is no such "default". Maybe that is not the full `.htaccess` style file you posted? Or your rule simply does not match at all, so no rewriting occurs. I suggest that 1. you use rewrite logging to find out what is going on inside your rewriting engine and 2.  you add a few more details to your question: requested URL, location of that `.htaccess` style file, host setup.

Comment: Hmm. It is the full `.htaccess` and there is no other such file anywhere else either. If I change the `^newsite/products$` to `^newsite/products1$` or any other name that isnt also a folder name - the file opens properly.

Comment: @arkascha added the info you asked for. Not sure what you mean by host setup.

Comment: Looks OK so far. Are you sure that `.htaccess` style files get interpreted _at all_ on that system? Try to place a clear syntax error in that file and try again, do you really get an error then?

Comment: Ah, wait, your RewriteRule does _not_ match if there is a trailing slash in the request. I suggest you modify it slightly: `RewriteRule ^newsite/products/?$ /newsite/products/product.php`.

Comment: @arkascha yes it does work as I explained above. If I change the request url to something different that isnt also a folder name, it works. Also, I've tried with both trailing / and without. (I'll sort that part later)

Comment: OK, then I come back to rewrite logging. Raise the level and check what is really going on. You are shown what patterns are tested against what requests and what matches and what not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off the directory slash to rewrite your file :

Try :

```
DirectorySlash off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^newsite/products$ /newsite/products/product.php [NC,L]
```

Don't add a trailing slash  in rule pattern

```
/newsite/products
```

will rewrite to

```
 /newsite/products/product.php
```

and

```
/newsite/products/
```

will open your "products" directory

Note- this is not a safe solution, if you remove the rule and DirectorySlash is off, Your index file will be ignored ,all directories  will start listing files and folders.